# Spilt the Main DB in Excel and Update the Values and Merge Them into one

Tags: database, excel, pivot, extract

I have a Database with 23000 Rows, Now we categorized as Like ( intrested, followup, not intressted) Now i want to create different work sheet for each category in that i have to update the sheet with other information which should be updated back in the main DB . Please help me how to do this.

I used Vlookup to do this but it is making my Workbook very slow in such a it take 1min to update value of single cell..

I tried Using Pivot Table to filter the values.since its dynamic when try to update the adjacent value to pivot table they are messing up.

in Sheet 1 I have the details of the Customer Like ( name,ph,email,CATEGORY(intrested,follow up, not interested),  status, etc)in the status i have the last follow up.

now in the sheet 2 i have to extract one category(eg. intrested) with email,name, ph with that ill follow up with those client and enter the informtion of communication which should go back to the sheet 1 in a new column.

Comment: having the vloopup i have same dynamic issue though. but still it useable because that categories will change once in a month only for the values

Comment: in Sheet 1 I have the details of the Customer Like ( name,ph,email, status, etc).

Comment: What is the layout of your worksheet? How can this be answered?

Comment: hope the updated info isclear

Comment: Are the categories in Column A?

Comment: Your question is too vague to answer correctly. Maybe edit your question and show how the layout of the worksheet is, and what you want as a result, then explain what you tried. If possible, supply an image as well. If you don't have enough reps for an image, then upload one to your google drive and supply a link to it.